# How can solve this amend and rebase problem?

Tags: git

I was trying to change a commit message, so I use the command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1
```

I changed `pick` to `reword` and then I didn't change the commit message after those changes.

Now, the message bellow appear in each git command. What should I do to not see this message anymore?

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Last commands done (2 commands done):
   reword b7ed559 Alteração no texto
   pick 73860e7 #5 Formatar texto
No commands remaining.
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '353bb3d'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)
```

Comment: Consider following the things that the git prompt recommends? Probably `git rebase --continue`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've tried it, but I got this: `error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': is at 464e7dbde0ad7ae44a5b4269d9329f23ecff58bc but expected 73860e73ca504b0af61217e2c8e4adcfcf9fc74e`
error: could not update refs/heads/master

Comment: @S_A Time to say `git rebase --abort` and start over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two problems won't tell you this:

1. Your problem is that after you use the command

> git rebase -i HEAD~1

-> One screen will appear to you change commit (it looks the same when after you use the command vim/vi on Linux). **The problem you exited it without using the correct save quit**. If necessary, you should review how to use the git -rebase

**Solution** cancels git rebase with the command:

> git rebase --abort

2. I recommend using **git --amend** in this case since you are changing the last commit message